# Clojure use of (for) with hiccup and noir

Tags: clojure, hiccup, noir

I am using clojure and hiccup (with noir) and I have this code:

```
(defn dataframe [id]
   (db/db-to-data id))

(defpartial drop-downs [nms]
  (for [nm (keys nms)] (drop-down nm (get nms nm))[:br])
  (submit-button "Refresh")  
  )

(defpage "/dataset/table/:id" {:keys [id]}
  (common/layout
    (form-to [:post (format "/dataset/table/%s" id)]
      (drop-downs {"alessio" [:col0], "test" [:col1]})
      )
   (html-table (dataframe id))))
```

My problem is with:

```
(for [nm (keys nms)] (drop-down nm (get nms nm))[:br])
```

I want to have multiple select in my form. The line above does that, but for some reason it does not consider [:br], so it does not break the lines. However, if I do this:

```
(form-to [:post (format "/dataset/table/%s" id)]
      (drop-down "Test1" "1")[:br]
      (drop-down "Test2" "2")[:br]
      )
```

The [:br] tag does work. I believe this is connected with how the (for) macro works, but I could not figure out the reason and how to fix it.

EDIT

As advised, I dropped the use of for. Final result below (which is Joost answer with a slight mod):

```
(mapcat #(vector (drop-down % (nms %)) [:br]) (keys nms))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That code doesn't even compile; `for` takes *exactly two* arguments.

If you want to put two items at once in the sequence returned by `for`, put them in a vector and unpack them later.

Though personally I prefer mapcat for these situations. Something like:

```
(into (form-to [:post (format "/dataset/table/%s" id)])
  (mapcat #(vector (drop-down % (nms %)) [:br]) nms))
```

Answer (score 1):

I put together a little something that doesn't use Noir or hiccup, but maybe will guide you in a better direction. It uses mapcat instead of for:

```
 (let [nms {"alessio" [:col0], "test" [:col1]}]
  (mapcat 
    (fn [mapentry] [[:dropdown (first mapentry) (second mapentry)] [:br]]) nms))

;;=> ([:dropdown "alessio" [:col0]] [:br] [:dropdown "test" [:col1]] [:br])
```

Comment: Thanks. This helped me understanding better the mapcat.

Answer (score 0):

Hiccup automatically "unwraps" seqs/lists (not vectors!) for you, so you can write this as:

```
(for [[k v] nms]
  (list (drop-down k v)
        [:br])))
```